# CFLAGS and assign more than one reference?

Tags: c++, c, makefile

I'm not used to working with C or C++ and I'm trying to let the compiler where to find references losses.

I have a configuration file called **configure** which creates the makefile.

Then to create the makefile I run:

```
CFLAGS=-I/usr/include/libxml2 ./configure  --enable-murder
```

As I run this line but given two references in CFLAGS?.

To be clear mais, compiling want to point to the references:

- /usr/include/libxml2
- /usr/include/libical

in   CFLAGS.

This is because I can not edit the makefile and I want to fix the following errors:

```
http_caldav.o: In function `is_valid_timerange':
http_caldav.c:(.text+0x3c86): undefined reference to `icaltime_is_valid_time'
http_caldav.c:(.text+0x3cd8): undefined reference to `icaltime_is_valid_time'
http_caldav.c:(.text+0x3d2a): undefined reference to `icaltime_is_date'
http_caldav.c:(.text+0x3d7c): undefined reference to `icaltime_is_date'
http_caldav.c:(.text+0x3dce): undefined reference to `icaltime_is_utc'
http_caldav.c:(.text+0x3e23): undefined reference to `icaltime_is_utc'
http_caldav.o: In function `parse_comp_filter':
http_caldav.c:(.text+0x3e7d): undefined reference to `xmlStrcmp'
http_caldav.c:(.text+0x3e98): undefined reference to `xmlGetProp'
http_caldav.c:(.text+0x3eb7): undefined reference to `xmlStrcmp'
http_caldav.c:(.text+0x3f02): undefined reference to `xmlStrcmp'
http_caldav.c:(.text+0x3f19): undefined reference to `xmlStrcmp'
http_caldav.c:(.text+0x3f46): undefined reference to `xmlStrcmp'
http_caldav.c:(.text+0x3f71): undefined reference to `xmlStrcmp'
http_caldav.o:http_caldav.c:(.text+0x3f9c): more undefined references to `xmlStrcmp' follow
http_caldav.o: In function `parse_comp_filter':
http_caldav.c:(.text+0x4077): undefined reference to `xmlFree'
http_caldav.c:(.text+0x40cc): undefined reference to `xmlStrcmp'
http_caldav.c:(.text+0x40d9): undefined reference to `icaltimezone_get_utc_timezone'
http_caldav.c:(.text+0x410f): undefined reference to `xmlGetProp'
http_caldav.c:(.text+0x412d): undefined reference to `icaltime_from_string'
http_caldav.c:(.text+0x4171): undefined reference to `xmlFree'
http_caldav.c:(.text+0x41a0): undefined reference to `icaltime_from_timet_with_zone'
http_caldav.c:(.text+0x41f2): undefined reference to `xmlGetProp'
http_caldav.c:(.text+0x4210): undefined reference to `icaltime_from_string'
http_caldav.c:(.text+0x4254): undefined reference to `xmlFree'
http_caldav.c:(.text+0x4283): undefined reference to `icaltime_from_timet_with_zone'
```

config.log

```
gcc-4.7.real: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
gcc-4.7.real: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3214: $? = 4
configure:3203: gcc -qversion >&5
gcc-4.7.real: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'
gcc-4.7.real: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
conftest.c:13:28: fatal error: ac_nonexistent.h: No such file or directory
conftest.c:56:26: fatal error: minix/config.h: No such file or directory
conftest.c:37:9: error: unknown type name 'not'
conftest.c:37:15: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'universal'
conftest.c:37:15: error: unknown type name 'universal'
gcc-4.7.real: error: unrecognized option '-R'
```

My OS is Debian 7.

Comment: Do you want to add two include paths with `CFLAGS`?

Comment: Those are link time errors.  Adding more paths to CFLAGS will not help, as it's likely finding the headers.  You might need to install the development packages for those libraries to get them to link.

Comment: Doesn't `configure` complain about missing stuff?

Comment: @meaning-matters, `configure` (if it is an autoconf `configure` file) will complain about missing stuff, unless it's not testing for them, in this case if it can link the libraries.

Comment: @ldav1s I have already installed the development packages but not how to solve these problems references. Although I still unsolved.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to add two include paths, enclose them in quotes

```
CFLAGS="-I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/libical" ./configure --enable-murder
```

To fix the linker errors, you must add the libraries with `LDLIBS`, e.g.

```
CFLAGS="..." LDLIBS="-lxml2 -lical" ./configure --enable-murder
```

Comment: It's typically better to add the variables as _arguments_ to the `configure` script, not into the environment.  So, `./configure --enable-murder CFLAGS="..." LDLIBS="..."`

Comment: @ldav1s Now try this and yet I still can not fix it. Sorry but not work with C or C + + and am trying to make this work.
I want to learn and fix it. Any suggestions of what else I can do?.

Comment: @ldav1s I found a config.log file. This was created to run the file configue. Now edit the question adding some errors I saw in the.

Comment: @ldav1s I think I found the solution! down at least a few mistakes.
Instead of using LDLIBS use LDFLAGS. Now all references to me are being sqlite3_column_int.

Comment: @MariaJosé The config.log snippet is just configure checking a few things. If the build runs and has only `sqlite3_column_int` as an undefined reference, you must add `-lsqlite3` to `LDLIBS`/`LDFLAGS`. And make sure SQLite is installed, of course.

Comment: @ldav1s Thanks!, that stay fixed. Now he was looking for other references that I need: undefined reference to: Parse_MIME, vObjectUStringZValue, cleanVObject, cleanStrTbl, vObjectName, cleanStrTbl, initPropIterator, fakeCString, nextVObject,moreIteration.

Comment: @MariaJosé I don't know anything about all these symbols. You should look for the prerequisites of the package, you're trying to build and install the needed developer libraries, usually named something `lib...-dev`. Anyway, configure should tell you about missing libraries already.